# Formula field to create a rating from a series of picklist values and checkbox field to update a WFR Field Update with rating from 1 - 8

Tags: workflow

WE are creating a workflow rule, field update formula. From a WFR.  My users are requesting have one [Response]pickist and one checkbox [Response] TRUE/FALSE  to update a Priority rating from the entries entered in these two above fields.:

1. Field to Update
2. List item
3. Aftercare Priority Field Data Type  Text

My field update formula is below,

```
CASE (1, 
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Email sent”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “FALSE”), “1”, 1,0), 8,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Phoned, message left”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “FALSE”), “1”, 1,0), 7,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Email sent”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “TRUE”), “1”, 1,0), 6,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Phoned, message left”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “TRUE”), “1”, 1,0), 5,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Phone, no option to leave message”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “FALSE”), “1”, 1,0), 4,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “no CBTA Response”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “FALSE”), “1”, 1,0), 3,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “Phone, no option to leave message”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “TRUE”), “1”, 1,0), 2,
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( AC_Aftercare_Response__c, “no CBTA Response”), 
AND (AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, “TRUE”), “1”, 1,0), 1,)
```

---

Error: Syntax error. Found ')'

Should I change the Checkbox: Bite Incident to a picklist ( Yes/No ) instead?

Advice would be welcomed.  So close... What is the best option for this to work?

Kind regards

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in the code. please go through the formula [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) to have a better understanding of the syntax.

Comment: The detail is as follows,

The new formula field:  Priority  ( will populate the custom text field a value 1, 2,3 4,5,6,7 or 8 pending the following selected values from an existing Field (picklist value) Response ( 1 of 4 values) to select and if the checkbox: Bite Incident is checked or not.)

Example of upates from the end users.

If (checkbox) Bite Incident = TRUE and (Picklist field) Response = no CBTA response then priority = 1
If Bite Incident = TRUE and Response = Phone, no option to leave message then priority = 2

Answer (score 0):

You've got your syntax all turned around; I'm not sure how you got there at all. That said, it looks like the fix is easy enough:

```
CASE(
    AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
    "Email Sent", 6,
    "Phoned, message left", 5,
    "Phone, no option to leave message", 2,
    "no CBTA Response", 1, 0
) + 
IF(
    AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c, 
    0, 
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,""), 
        0, 
        2
    )
)
```

You'll want to read the documentation for CASE and IF to see how they work.

Comment: The detail is as follows,

The new formula field:  Priority  ( will populate the custom text field a value 1, 2,3 4,5,6,7 or 8 pending the following selected values from an existing Field (picklist value) Response ( 1 of 4 values) to select and if the checkbox: Bite Incident is checked or not.)

Example of updates from the end users.
The custom field has to display _ {Priority} 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8

Comment: IF(AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c = true,
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
"Email sent", 6,
"Phoned, message left", 5,
"Phone, no option to leave message", 2,
"no CBTA Response", 1,
0),
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
"Email sent", 8,
"Phoned, message left", 7,
"Phone, no option to leave message", 4,
"no CBTA Response", 3,
0)
)

Comment: IF(AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c = true,
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
"Email sent", 6,
"Phoned, message left", 5,
"Phone, no option to leave message", 2,
"no CBTA Response", 1,
0),
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
"Email sent", 8,
"Phoned, message left", 7,
"Phone, no option to leave message", 4,
"no CBTA Response", 3,
0)
)              I tried this format: Error: Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type (Text).
Description
Help Text

Comment: @CharmsRhule Your original code was returning a number, so I stuck with it. If you need it as text, use `TEXT(...original formula here...)`.

Comment: I have changed the formula: IF
(AC_Aftercare_Bite_Incident__c = true,
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,

"Email sent", "6",
"Phoned, message left", "5",
"Phone, no option to leave message", "2",
"no CBTA Response", "1",
""),
CASE(AC_Aftercare_Response__c,
"Email sent", "8",
"Phoned, message left", "7",
"Phone, no option to leave message", "4",
"no CBTA Response", "3",
"0")
)
 which now works